# calling function in express route that returns middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, joi

I am creating a custom function for handling API request validation. It is done as follows:

```js
export function validateBody(schema: string): (req: ExpressRequest, res: ExpressResponse, next: ExpressNextFunction) => void {
    return function (req: ExpressRequest, res: ExpressResponse, next: ExpressNextFunction): void | ExpressResponse {
        // Some operation
        next();
    }
}
```

It is used in an api route as a function call that returns a middleware

```js
router.route('/api/users/currentuser').get(validateBody('signIn'), (req: ExpressRequest, res: ExpressResponse, next: ExpressNextFunction) => {
```

I am getting the following lint error

```bash
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: ExpressRequest, res: ExpressResponse, next: ExpressNextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: ExpressRequest, res: ExpressResponse, next: ExpressNextFunction) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
        Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
          Property 'value' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' but required in type 'ExpressRequest'.ts(2769)
types.ts(4, 5): 'value' is declared here.
index.d.ts(222, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

It is expecting a "RequestHandleParam" type which I tried using but that start throwing error in "validateBody" function definition. Any solution or workaround is greatly appreciated.

**Ps:**  using javascript instead of typescript works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler interface to use is [RequestHandler](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L120-L126). It implicitly types all the request handler function parameters which cuts down on a lot of boilerplate

```ts
import { RequestHandler } from "express";

const validateBody =
  (schema: string): RequestHandler =>
  (_req, _res, next) => {
    next();
  };
```

Comment: I did that and that too wasn't working. What worked was instead of using custom interface that extends Request, Response, NextFunction, I modified the default Request, Response on global Express namespace and use them instead

Comment: @DrusePstrago I really have no idea what that means. The code in my answer works fine for me with absolutely no compilation issues